# How to access height used in wR x hR mode which I have set in Storyboard

Tags: swift, ios-autolayout, size-classes

I have TextField in my UI and I have given dynamic height(using Storyboard) for `wC x hR` and `wR x hR`, now when I add corner radius to the textfield programmatically `textField.layer.cornerRadius = textField.frame.height/2`,

I am getting the height which I have set for `wC x hR`.
Is there any method by which I can get the actual height used in the iPad or iPhone device?
I am getting 40 instead of 70 in iPad with `wR x hR`
[Use this image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpUVy.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are likely setting the `.cornerRadius` at the wrong point in the view layout... that is, you are calculating `textField.frame.height/2` before auto-layout sets the actual height.

Much easier approach is to sub-class `UITextField` and override `layoutSubviews()`, where you will update the `.cornerRadius` value:

```
class RoundTextField: UITextField {

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        layer.cornerRadius = bounds.size.height / 2.0
    }

}
```

Assign the Custom Class of your text field to `RoundTextField` ... in every other way, you can treat it as a standard text field.